# JavaScript: How to separate a U8IntArray?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a U8IntArray with 20 bytes and I want to separate it into two parts (first 8 bytes and byte 9 to 20):

```
var arr = new Uint8Array( 20 );
var part1 = arr.slice( 0, 8 );
var part2 = arr.slice( 8 );

console.info( part1, part2 );
```

Works in FireFox, but fails in Chrome and Internet-Explorer:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function*

Is there a easy way to slice the Uint8Array, which will work in all browsers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that Typed Arrays were initially defined by the [Typed Array Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/), which did not define any `slice` method in the `TypedArray` interface.

Now Typed Arrays are part of [ECMAScript 6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-typedarray-objects), but Internet Exporer don't support it completely.

So it will be safer to use only methods defined in the old spec. In this case, [`TypedArray.prototype.subarray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/subarray) should work since IE10.

```js
var arr = new Uint8Array( 20 );
var part1 = arr.subarray( 0, 8 );
var part2 = arr.subarray( 8 );
console.info( part1, part2 );
```

Another alternative is using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/slice) on the buffer instead of directly on the array, supported since IE11.

```js
var arr = new Uint8Array( 20 );
var part1 = new Uint8Array( arr.buffer.slice( 0, 8 ) );
var part2 = new Uint8Array( arr.buffer.slice( 8 ) );
console.info( part1, part2 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just saw it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313993/typedarray-prototype-slice-not-supported-on-chrome Ill mark your answer as correct in 10m (when it is possible)!

Comment: @Tream Good find, probably one question should be closed as a duplicate of the other. I think your question is more clear but, since I answered here, if I close the other one it could seem I abuse my dupehammer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) from the original buffer source, then specify the second and the third arguments to retrieve the expected bytes.

```
var arr = new Uint8Array( 20 );
var part1 = new Uint8Array(arr.buffer, 0, 8);
var part2 = new Uint8Array(arr.buffer, 8);
```

Just note that this method doesn't slice the original [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer).

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to separate arrays with variable size you need to store the size of the first array.  Here is an example that will some text to a binary array and then and remove the text from it.

```
var sText1 = "Some Text";
var buffer_with_text = AddTextToBinaryBuffer(sText1, buffer);
var ret = RemoveTextFromBinaryBuffer(buffer_with_text);
var sText2 = ret[0];
var buffer_no_text = ret[1];

function RemoveTextFromBinaryBuffer(buffer) {
    var arr = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var oLength = arr.subarray(0, 3);
    var sLength = oLength[0].toString(2).padStart(8, "0") +
        oLength[1].toString(2).padStart(8, "0") +
        oLength[2].toString(2).padStart(8, "0");
    var iLength = parseInt(sLength, 2);
    var oText = arr.subarray(3, 3 + iLength);
    var sText = new TextDecoder().decode(oText); //return text value
    var r = arr.subarray(3 + iLength);
    return [sText, new Uint8Array(r).buffer];
}

function AddTextToBinaryBuffer(s, buffer) {
    //output will have three parts: //123-abcdefg-101100010 [text length-text binary-binary stream]
    //first three numbers is the length of text binary array (max = 16,777,215)

    const oTextArray = new TextEncoder().encode(s);

    var sLength = (oTextArray.byteLength).toString(2).padStart(32, "0");
    const oLength = new Uint8Array(3);
    oLength[0] = parseInt(sLength.substring(0, 8), 2)
    oLength[1] = parseInt(sLength.substring(8, 16), 2)
    oLength[2] = parseInt(sLength.substring(16, 32), 2)

    var r = new Uint8Array([...oLength, ...oTextArray, ...new Uint8Array(buffer)]);
    return r.buffer;
}
```